# ARC - Retaining child objects NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

Is it proper that I have a Button which basically passes a NSManagedObject to a segue to load the next view, in the next view I load a child object of the parent NSManaged object. When i destroy that controller the NSManagedObject is still retained by the original button along with children. I assume it get released the next time I load that same data, because it overwrites that property of the NSManaged object. But is it bad that it retains all these child objects or is that normal?

Should / can I manually release these children by setting the property to nil at some point?

Let me give some more context to what I am seeing.

[image: Instruments]

Contents of -[Brand pages]

```
- (NSArray *) pages {


  NSLog(@"%@", [self edetail]);

  if ([self edetail] != nil) {

    NSArray *pgs = [[[self edetail] pages] allObjects];
    return [pgs sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sort_order" ascending:YES]]];
  }
  return [NSArray array];
}
```

Let's say I have a NSArray of objectA which we're a NSSet which I pulled from coredata and sorted. Then I iterate over each objectA in the Array and create a custom button class which has a property set to objectA. When the button is clicked I send a message up to my UINavigationController to segue to a page that uses that ObjectA to pull a certain child array/set of ObjectA and display the data in a custom grid.

According to instruments when I pop that UIViewController that I had passed ObjectA to, ObjectA is still retaining those child object, and ObjectA is still retained by my button. Is this really a bad design? It doesn't seem any worse than if my RootViewController was retaining a NSArray of those object and calling them by index.

I feel like through the course of using the app though, I may end up having actual references to every piece of data in core data, that's what worries me, that these children aren't released even after I don't need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The managed object context is responsible for the memory management of managed objects. That's a horrible sentence.

If you modify the properties of managed objects or create new ones, the assumption is that you want them to persist in the MOC, unless you roll it back or don't save. If you have a managed object held in a strong property, you're not leaking or really using extra memory - the MOC will turn objects into faults if it comes under memory pressure.

I'm a bit concerned by your statement that the *button* is retaining managed objects, that doesn't sound like a good design. If you are passing a managed object as part of a segue, the button doesn't need to have or keep a reference to it - that's the view controllers job.

Comment: Its a button wrapped in a view controller. But what your saying is I shouldn't load each view controller with the NSManagedObject used to generate it, and then pass that instance of NSManagedObject to the next push segue in my navigation controller?

Comment: I don't understand your first comment. Re your edit, personally I think an array retained by the view controller is better (more MVC) - but what you have will work, its a matter of taste. I don't think you have anything to worry about regarding memory management.

Comment: k, sounds good, i was just concerned about the memory footprint growing as attached more data to my NSManagedObjects.

Comment: CoreData's _PFAllocate object seems to be the only thing retaining it so i guess thats delt with by the ManagedObjectContext so i shouldn't have much to worry about.